# Controlling one user's access to another user's resources based on RBAC

Tags: ejb, authorization, access-control, rbac, abac

I have a scenario where a user with a specific role is allowed to call an EJB method based on his own id . On the EJB bean i have `@RolesAllowed` annotation with the specific role for the user. For the role based checks the method invocation works fine however if the user in picture calls the bean method passing the id of another user the method still gets invoked . How do i avoid this scenario with RBAC or do i need to achieve this using any alternate way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application logic (the authentication logic) should prevent the call to the method using another user identity. In a way, when you do that, you are spoofing someone else's identity.

The `@RolesAllowed` annotation should therefore use roles that are retrieved based on a user id retrieved from the framework, not from a value manually passed by the user. To give you an example in the Servlet world, you'd use the method getUserPrincipal() of the HttpServletRequest object.

I'm quoting here a paragraph from a Java EE 6 tutorial on servlets. You can extrapolate the same principles to ejbs.

> Checking Caller Identity Programmatically
>   In general, security management should be enforced by the container in a manner that is transparent to the web component. The security API described in this section should be used only in the less frequent situations in which the web component methods need to access the security context information.
>
> - Servlet 3.0 specifies the following methods that enable you to access security information about the component’s caller:
> - getRemoteUser, which determines the user name with which the client authenticated. The getRemoteUser method returns the name of the remote user (the caller) associated by the container with the request. If no user has been authenticated, this method returns null.
> - isUserInRole, which determines whether a remote user is in a specific security role. If no user has been authenticated, this method returns false. This method expects a String user role-name parameter.
>
> The security-role-ref element should be declared in the deployment descriptor with a role-name subelement containing the role name to be passed to the method. Using security role references is discussed in Declaring and Linking Role References.
>
> - getUserPrincipal, which determines the principal name of the current user and returns a java.security.Principal object. If no user has been authenticated, this method returns null. Calling the getName method on the Principal returned by getUserPrincipal returns the name of the remote user.
>
> Your application can make business-logic decisions based on the information obtained using these APIs.

Source: [Using Programmatic Security with Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html)